# Upwork Duplicate Account

Tags: account, odesk

I had made an account on **Odesk** but when **upwork** came I made another account there and in the meant time I opened my old odesk account on upwork.
Now I have a project on my old upwork account and today I saw a notification about the video calling verification from the upwork, I quickly disabled my new upwork account and since then I am worried that if I do video call with them, how many chances are there that they won't disable my account for duplication reason?
Any help or suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we're not customer support for (your favorite company)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 1):

Just continue with one account only and disable another account. You are safe!